# Can't get Umano's SlidingUpPanel to slide correctly when using a clickable DragView

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using Umano's `SlidingUpPanelLayout` located [here](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel), but I'm having trouble when I specify a DragView in the XML layout. When I don't specify that my drag view can handle touch events, the slider works perfectly. However, when I do something like...

```
SlidingUpPanelLayout slider = (SlidingUpPanelLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout);
slider.setEnableDragViewTouchEvents(true);
```

it allows the click events to register in my drag view, but it messes with the functionality of my `SlidingUpPanelLayout`. Now I have to start dragging the drag view much lower in the view (practically the bottom of my page), instead of it allowing me to drag from the top of the drag view like it would had I not called `slider.setEnableDragViewTouchEvents(true);`

I tried disecting the code, and my guess is it has something to do with the `onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)` event, specifically the switch case for (action) with the `if(mIsUsingDragViewTouchEvents)` clause.

I've tried multiple things to try to fix this, but I can't seem to get it to work. Does anyone have any easy solutions?

Comment: I have the same problem and I couldn't find a solution for this. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Yes I was. Go to the code that initializes `SlidingUpPanelLayout` with inputs Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle (mine is on line 325, but I edited the file a bit, so it will probably be a bit off for you).

They call the function `mDragHelper = ViewDragHelper.create(this, 0.5f, new DragHelperCallback());` After countless hours of searching, I found that the 0.5f was a sensitivity for the touch (where 1.0f) is default. Setting this value to 2.0f greatly changed the responsiveness of my app when trying to drag the panel.

Comment: No problem! Such a huge headache for such a small, but irritating bug.

Comment: Please answer your own question and mark it as answer so other users can easily find it.